# Mat-sort not working after dataSource change

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

Mat-sort not working after dataSource change. From the parent after adding new employee to employee array, I am sending the new copy of array to child.
I could see new rows in the child mat table, pagination working fine but sorting is not working properly

parent :

```
<app-employeeList-list [EmployeeList]='EmployeeList' ></app-employeeList-list>
```

child:

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ["hireDt", "jobTitle"];

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IEmployee>;


  @Input() EmployeeList: IEmployee[];

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;

  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

   ngOnChanges() {

   // console.log(this.EmployeeList) ---showing all employees including newly 
                                       added employee 

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.EmployeeList);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

  }
```

child html:

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z4">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>

      <!-- hireDt Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="hireDt">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Hire Date </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.hireDt | date}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- jobTitle Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="jobTitle">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Job Title </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.jobTitle}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;">
      </tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator showFirstLastButtons [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,15,20]"></mat-paginator>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you add your html ? are you using `ngif` ?

Comment: rebinding mat table's data source on `ngOnChanges` is a BAD idea. there are very few use-cases that require you to use `ngOnChanges`, fewer even, for using it without a switch-case in it. this is not one of them.

Comment: @Stavm Could you please suggest me another way of doing this. My child component has only mat table, no other elements. I tried binding obeservable<IEmployee[]> but mattable not refreshing upon emiting new value from  obeservable

Comment: @NadhirFalta No I am not using ngIf

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you reinitialized the datasource every time `ngOnChanges` emits, try it this way:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}           

ngOnChanges() {
  console.log(this.EmployeeList) ---showing all employees including newly 
                                                       added employee 
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource.data = this.EmployeeList;
}
```